# PHP - MySQL, think the $result is empty on some moments when there should be elements in

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP page with 3 dropdownlists on it. Everytime with an 'onchange' event a javascript docs get's the selected value's and transfers it to a php function, where I can transfer them to my mysql-database and get results out of them. This thing works perfect, but not when I apply my logic to define which function I should call

My php page contains the effective logic (see code-box) and underneed there are the 2functions with the actions. The function do work, but the problem is this. There's the possibility in the if-else construction that the functions can be called on 2 different moments. The first time in the if-else construction both of the calls are succesfull and the result is what it should be, the second moments it seems that the $result parameter is empty?

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed with error: ".mysql_error());

$aantal = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($amount == 0){


echo "<p>This combination does not exist</p>";
    }
    else {
        // lists are empty
        if($soort == 'Empty' && $land == 'Empty' && $jaar == 'Empty'){
        }
        else {
            if ($aantal > 2){
                maketable($aantal, $result); // -> **succesfull call**
            }
            else if($aantal == 1){
                makedetails($result); // -> **succesfull call**
            }
            else {
                $first = mysql_result($result, 0);
                $second = mysql_result($result, 1);
                if (($second - $first) == 1){
                    makedetails($result); //  -> **does not work**
                }
                else {
                    maketable($aantal, $result); //  -> **does not work**
                }
            }
        }
    }

function maketable($aantal, $result) { … }
function makedetails($result){ … }
```

greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to fetch my result once more to make it possible to loop through my array once again.

```
$first = mysql_result($result, 0);
$second = mysql_result($result, 1);
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed with error: ".mysql_error());
```

But thanks for the help!

greetings

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your query, so we can't tell what's going on. But mysql_result by default returns the FIRST field in the specified row, if you don't explicitly state which field to use, so unless your query is

```
SELECT somenumber FROM yourtable ...
```

then your mysql_result is going to be fetching who knows what. Note that you're also comparing that default 'first' value from two different rows - are you sure the query is actually returning 2+ rows of data?

Comment: The query does work, been working with this query on my site for over 2 years. The problem is in the logic of the php. Cause the first time it returns the right elements, but second time not anymore, and it is with the same query..

Comment: I just edited the logic to call the right functions now to make my website correct and working with the same sql query that return the correct values (tested them far to much to be sure now! )

Answer (score 0):

$aantal is the number of rows affected by the query. Your logic does not work because you're trying to use query results when there are no rows affected.

Your logic:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$number_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($number_of_rows > 2)
{
   //do something
}
else if ( $number_of_rows == 1)
{
   //Do something else
}
else if( $number_of_rows == 2 OR $number_of_rows == 0)
{
   // Do something else (the part which fails)
}
```

The only way to reach that part and not fail is if the rows affected are exactly 2. When they are 0, the query didn't return anything and you are trying to access an empty result set.

Comment: in the first if when the amount = 0, i can enter this part succesfully, and the echo is returned. When the amount is 0, there are no actions done with the result because indeed there are no elements to do stuff with.. Also when it's nog 0 the else is called and the other cases are checked